# How to initialise a variable of datatype Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter and have been following a flutter tutorial, in which there is a variable that was declared as 'Stream usersStream,chatRoomsStream;', since it was giving me a compile time error, I added the keyword 'late' in front of it. This solved my compile time error. However, it is giving me a runtime error saying : LateInitialisationError: Field chatRoomsStream has not been initialised. How do i solve this?

I couldnt find any solution on the net addressing this exact problem

Answer (score 0):

## Late keyword

The `late` keyword basically means you'll give your variable a value later, sometime before you attempt to use it.

For example, you can declare a variable like this (example with `ScrollController`):

```
late ScrollController controller;
```

and then later, for example in your `initState()` method, you can give it a value:

```
controller = ScrollController();
```

First, the variable has a "promise" that you'll give it a value soon. Attempting to use it before you give it that value will result in an error. Then, after you set it to `ScrollController`, you can use it normally.

## Streams

You can create a stream like this (example with stream of `double`s):

```
StreamController<double> controller = StreamController<double>();
```

Then:

```
Stream stream = controller.stream;
```

to access the stream.

You can then interact with the stream through its controller like so:

```
controller.add(99.0);
```

You can listen for changes on the stream like this:

```
StreamSubscription<double> streamSubscription = stream.listen((streamValuesAsTheyCome) {
  print('Value from controller: $streamValuesAsTheyCome');
});
```

Remember to also cancel your streams when you're done using them like this:

```
streamSubscription.cancel();
```

Let me know if this helps, good luck!

Comment: This is what the stream usersStream is getting: usersStream=await DatabaseMethods().getUserByUserName(searchUsernameEdittingController.text); The method getUserByUserName() has a rturn type of Future <QuerySnapshot> so i dont understand how i initialise it

Comment: I tried using Stream<QuerySnapshot> usersStream=new Stream<QuerySnapshot>(); but this shows the error: abstract classes cant be instantiated